# Pod install gives a error message

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I want to use QuickBlox Api, but during the installation 'pod' an error:

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `Quickblox-WebRTC (~> 2.0.0)` required by `Podfile`

Where is the error?

Comment: Can you provide your podfile content?

Comment: of cource:

my Podfile:

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC', '~> 2.0.0'

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you using? You can check by running `gem list cocoapods`. There's a known issue with 0.39 related to version comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your pod file should look like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'YourProjectName' do
    pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```